# Change Default Settings when Creating Objects on Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2015

OK, I might not exactly be using the right terminology here... but When I'm in the form designer in Visual Studio, and I add an item (lets use a Label as as an example), is there a way to change the default properties when adding an item?

For example, Anytime I add a label, I might want AutoSize = False, TextAlign = MiddleLeft, Size = 100, 23 - Without manually changing the properties.  Can this be done? How?

Thanks!

Comment: Bueller..... Bueller.....

Comment: seriously, nobody????

Comment: come on?  SOMEBODY has to know if this is possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I saw this question, I didn't know if you could, so I started looking through the entirity of VS2015, but could not find any way to change the default values of an item, kind of a shame, it's indeed very annoying to change the value everytime if you need to create about the same label. you could change the DLL values, but I DO NOT recomend doing this!

Edit:
you can ofcourse create 1 element with these properties and then copy paste them in the same project, but this means that you need to set those values everytime you create a new project/solution

Answer (score 1):

This is built in in VS and should not be changed. In order to do this you would need to change values in the built in dlls in the program itself and thats a process and also not one anyone with their right mind would ever recommend.

Create a label, change the properties to the desiered values and for the rest of the labels simply copy the original one.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if/how i can award you the bounty as well, you both provided the answer within a minute or 2. it's only fair.

Comment: As far as I know only the accepted answer gets the bounty. No worris m8